# Select a folder with the SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

everyone.I'm just confused that how could i select a folder with the SaveFileDialog.Is there any way to customize the SaveFileDialog to allow select a folder?Looking forward to your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx)  instead of SaveFileDialog.

> Prompts the user to select a folder.

Example from MSDN.

```
DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
if( result == DialogResult.OK )
{
    string folderName = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    //........
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the [`SaveFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) consider using the [`FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) for selecting a folder.

This will allow you to select a folder path, otherwise selecting a folder with the [`SaveFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) is nuanced at best and not recommended.